# Julia: How to avoid auto-promotion type changes?

Tags: types, julia

For example:

```
n::Uint8 = 0x00
x::Uint8 = n + 0x10
ERROR: type: typeassert: expected Uint8, got Uint64
```

I assume this happens because `methods(+)` for `a::Uint8, b::Uint8` is not defined so `n` is auto-promoted to `Uint64`. Is there a better way to deal with this than casting everything back to it's pre-promoted type after every operation? Isn't this something that the interpreter should be able to handle automatically (i.e. if it's told `x` should be assigned a `Uint8` after the addition)?

Comment: This behavior was a deliberate choice in julia 0.3, to reduce the risk of overflow.

Comment: The only case for which I would have found old behaviour useful was I think one for which it didn't apply (int64 -> bigint doesn't auto promote).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there is a better way in Julia 0.3 than

```
julia> typeof(uint8(0x00 + 0x10))
UInt8
```

but in Julia 0.4 you don't need to worry as it doesn't do that automatic promotion anymore:

```
julia> typeof(0x00 + 0x10)
UInt8
```

Comment: Ah yeah I hadn't used Julia in a while -  I just tried it in `0.4`, it seems `+` methods for smaller int and uint types got added to dispatch.

Comment: Yeah there was some logic to the old behavior, but I think for most people the new behavior makes a lot more sense.

Comment: Note that `x+y` does not check for overflow on either julia 0.3 or julia 0.4. If that's a concern, on 0.4 you'll need to mimic the promotion behavior yourself, e.g., `convert(UInt8, convert(UInt16, x) + y)` for `x` and `y` both `UInt8`. On 0.4 `convert` will throw an error if the resulting value overflows `UInt8`.